# Using a different case for a variable name doesn't work

Tags: php

What the heck is wrong with this:

```
if  ($bb[$id][0] == "bizz")  {
    $BoxType = "bus_box";
} else {
    $Boxtype = "home_box";
}
<div class="<? echo $BoxType; ?>">
```

`$bb[$id][0]` can either be 'bizz' or 'home' but no matter what it stops after the first step.

Comment: Could you edit that so the code reads correctly? And could you also explain what you have done to test it.

Comment: Thanks - couldn't see the $wood for the $trees!

Comment: This seems to me like a coffee buffer underrun error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP variables are case sensitive. The 'T' in `$BoxType` is lower case in the else block.

Answer (score 5):

Not entirely related to your question (which has already been answered), but you may be interested in the ternary operator :)

```
<div class="<?= $bb[$id][0] == "bizz" ? "bus_box" : "home_box" ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Explain what you mean by "it stops after the first step".  Tom is correct, $BoxType and $Boxtype are the not same variables, but it sounds like $BoxType is always getting "bus_box". If it were really "stopping after the first step", $BoxType would just be whatever it was initialized to in the event that $bb[$id][0] was "bizz" and $Boxtype would be "home_box".